# WP Query by Gutenberg block and get its attribute

Tags: wp-query, block-editor, embed

I need to fetch on the front page youtube video from the latest post where was used gutenberg youtube block.

I guess I need:

1) query such posts

2) extract the youtube URL from the block

Is there a way how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of googling I came up with following solution. Maybe once will help to someone.

1) query post where is used gutenberg youtube block:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    's'                 => 'core-embed/youtube',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

2) extract the URL from youtube block of the post

```
$post_id = 117;
$post = get_post($post_id);
$blocks = parse_blocks( $post->post_content );


function findYoutubeBlock(array $blocks) {
    return $blocks['blockName'] == 'core-embed/youtube';
}


if (has_block('core-embed/youtube', $post_id)) {
    $youtube_block = reset(array_filter($blocks, 'findYoutubeBlock'));
    $youtube_url =  $youtube_block['attrs']['url'];
}
```

Comment: note that this will not work in modern WP as the youtube block was retired in favour of a youtube block variant of the `core/embed` block. It would be more efficient and reliable to store a term/flag named `has-video` in a private taxonomy when the post is saved or updated. This would also give you a screen in WP Admin that shows all posts that have this, as well as make the frontend `WP_Query` significantly faster, and avoid having to parse blocks a second time on the frontend